# Please implement Twitter sharing of questions on mobile design

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, mobile-web

I would like to share a Stack Overflow question via Twitter.  I'm using my iPhone, and there's no "share" widget on the mobile view of SO.  Instead, I have to copy & paste the question title and link into Twitter.  (The link doesn't even come with the referral code for the Announcer badge.)

It could be much easier for me to share questions and answers from my mobile device on Twitter.

Comment: FYI If you click the share button below a question that show a link with the referral code.

Comment: Yes, but "Share" isn't present on SO's mobile stylesheet, so I can't get it if I'm not at my desk.

Comment: True, was just pointing it out as you mentioned no referral code. :)

Answer (score 2):

Sharing on Twitter is now available.

Screenshot from iPhone Safari:

> [image]